# How can we read the following statement?

Tags: c++

Say that we have the following statements:

```
typedef itk::Image<double, 2>  FloatImageType;

void CreateF(FloatImageType::Pointer image)
{
...
}
```

I know what `::` means in the function. But, in this case, do we read it as follows?

*class Pointer is a member of the class FloatImageType*

Thanks.

Comment: `::` means in the scope of, not in the function.

Comment: @40two. Thanks for your reply. And, in this case, it means that we have a `Pointer` in the scope of `FloatImageType`, that is pointing (referencing) to an image of type `FloatImageType`. Is that correct this way?

Comment: Most probable, `Pointer` is a `typedef` in the definition of template class `Image`. I can't tell you much if I don't have the definition of template class `Image`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what `Pointer` actually is.

Case 1:

```
namespace itk
{
    template <class T, int X>
    struct Image
    {
        typedef int Pointer;
    };
}
```

This is called a "member typedef".

Case 2:

```
namespace itk
{
    template <class T, int X>
    struct Image
    {
        struct Pointer
        {
        };
    };
}
```

This is called a "nested class".

Case 3:

```
namespace itk
{
    template <class T, int X>
    struct Image
    {
        static int const Pointer = 0;
    };
}
```

This is obviously not a type at all but just a static member variable.

Comment: I suppose we can narrow it down by observing the itk documentation. A quick search failed to find me a proper documentation reference. http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide

Comment: Case 3 is irrelevant, in this case `Pointer` doesn't define a type. Thus, it can't specify the type of the input argument of function `void CreateF(FloatImageType::Pointer image)`.

Comment: @40two: You are right, but from the question it is not clear if the OP actually tried to do this (encountering a compiler error).

Answer (score 0):

> But, in this case, do we read it as follows?
>   class Pointer is a member of the class FloatImageType

No, it reads as follows to the compiler:

> I expect an instance of type `Pointer` as defined in the `FloatImageType` template class (without telling what template parameters, so I'm fine with any).
>   I do **not** want an instance of some type that is (maybe by accident) called `Pointer` and that maybe exists in global namespace, or one that you pull out of somewhere else, I don't care. I am **explicitly** requesting one that belongs to `FloatImageType`, nothing different.

(It is also necessary to explicitly resolve the type of `Pointer` as being a member of `FloatImageType` since it's inside a class definition (or template class, as it happens) and wouldn't otherwise be visible or "known".)